# how to show the foreign characters in tpl.php file

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I would like to set my website as Multilingual. I typed some Korean words (eg."한국어") in tpl.php file, but when I check my webpage, it shows me some question marks (eg."???").
Here is the code:

```
 <div class="row">
     <h2>한국어</h2>
     <p></p>
 </div>
```

I think it might be somewhere I need to set first. Does anyone know about this? I really appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your theme is using the utf-8 character set.  You can see this in the headers of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

You'll also want to make sure that the web server you are using to serve the page is sending the correct HTTP header as the response (you can use the web developer inspector tool in either Firefox or Chrome to see this).  It should be:

```
Content Type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

If your browser is set to use a different content-type encoding this might also explain the difference.

Comment: You also need to ensure your documents are saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: My document is encoding by UTF-8. In addition, I added the header and found `<meta charset="utf-8" />` when I viewed source code. But I still got question marks.

Comment: which web server are you using to serve pages?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your update. I think I am using HTTP for my website.

Comment: I meant that the web server configuration can have a bearing on how character sets are handled. Apache? Nginx?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I believe it's Apache.

Comment: In which case check this SO entry for the correct way to ensure Apache is handling content as utf8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-server